# How to mute/unmute default sound output

Tags: command-line, audio, pulseaudio, devices, alsa

What's the *generic* way to mute/unmute my system's default sound output?

```bsh
$ amixer set Master mute
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0

$ amixer scontrols
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',3
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',4
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',5
```

I know the sound control had been moving away from amixer to Pulseaudio, however, I'm still able to [use the ALSA "Master" control](https://superuser.com/questions/805525/why-is-unmute-not-working-with-amixer-command/1690637#1690637) in my Debian 10, but not my Ubuntu 21.10, see above.

There is `pactl set-sink-mute 0 1` from https://superuser.com/questions/805525/, but I tried it but that doesn't work for my Ubuntu 21.10 above.

All in all, I just need a *generic* way to mute/unmute my system's default sound output that is good across all my machines and all my Linuxes, just like the ALSA "Master" control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using this command for ages now:

```
pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle
```

This mutes/unmutes depending on the current state.

---

Also to increase volume: `pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +3%`
or decrease volume: `pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -3%`

Answer (score 3):

to mute:

```
pactl set-sink-mute `pactl get-default-sink` 1
```

to unmute :

```
pactl set-sink-mute `pactl get-default-sink` 0
```

Answer (score 0):

With the toggle option, it mutes everything.  However, toggle Master does not unmute everything.

So, if we toggle Master, and always unmute the sub-channels, then Master will toggle, and the (sub-) channels will always unmute.

So I made a 3 line script ::

```
will@will:~$ cat toggle 
amixer -c 1 set Master toggle
amixer -c 1 set Headphone unmute
amixer -c 1 set Speaker unmute
```

[image]

Then bind the script to the key ... because I'm to lazy to press the Fn - mute / vol+ / vol- combination for my keyboard.
[image]

Comment: Thanks but please note my "amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master'" in OP. Welcome aboard anyway.

Comment: You didn't specify the card ? 

'-c 1' in my example

Comment: OK, but I don't have the environment anymore to test your command. Thanks though. BTW, please run `amixer scontrols` and post your result.